# Remove from file a string and another string and everything after it

Tags: linux, sed, text-parsing, in-place

Say I have a file `teams` with contents as follows:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Version=1.0
Type=Application
Name=Microsoft Teams - Preview
Comment=Microsoft Teams for Linux is your chat-centered workspace in Office 365.
Exec=teams %U
Icon=teams
Terminal=false
StartupNotify=true
StartupWMClass=Microsoft Teams - Preview
Categories=Network;
MimeType=x-scheme-handler/msteams;
X-KDE-Protocols=teams
Actions=QuitTeams;
X-GNOME-UsesNotifications=true;

[Desktop Action QuitTeams]
Name=Quit Teams
```

I'd like to remove a line `Actions=QuitTeams;`. This seems easy:

```
sed -i '/Actions=QuitTeams;/d' teams
```

Also, I'd like to remove a line `[Desktop Action QuitTeams]` and everything that comes after it (there could be new lines).
This also seems easy:

```
sed -i '/[Desktop Action QuitTeams]]/,$d' teams
```

My question is: how do I do the two steps in one sed execution, i.e. combine all the regexes into one? `Sed` is preferred but other tools are welcomed, too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try using `sed`'s `-e` option (see [3.8 Multiple commands syntax](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/html_node/Multiple-commands-syntax.html)):

```
$ sed -i -e '/Actions=QuitTeams;/d' -e '/[Desktop Action QuitTeams]]/,$d' teams
$ cat teams
[Desktop Entry]
Version=1.0
Type=Application
Name=Microsoft Teams - Preview
Comment=Microsoft Teams for Linux is your chat-centered workspace in Office 365.
Exec=teams %U
Icon=teams
Terminal=false
StartupNotify=true
StartupWMClass=Microsoft Teams - Preview
Categories=Network;
MimeType=x-scheme-handler/msteams;
X-KDE-Protocols=teams
X-GNOME-UsesNotifications=true;
```

Comment: Or with GNU sed, you can chain the expressions with `';'`, e.g. `sed -i '/Actions=QuitTeams;/d;/\[Desktop Action QuitTeams\]/,/^$/d' file` (slightly different in it removes from `[Desktop Action QuitTeams]` to the next blank line -- just in case that isn't at the end of the file)

Answer (score 1):

You are using `-i` inplace modification option as is, so you are using a GNU sed. In a GNU sed, you can also use

```
sed -z -i 's/[^\n]*Actions=QuitTeams;[^\n]*\n\?\|[^\n]*\[Desktop Action QuitTeams].*//g' teams
```

See the [online demo](https://ideone.com/D8ioYF).

The `-z` option slurps line endings and the line endings become "visible" to the regex.

The sed regex is a POSIX BRE compliant pattern that matches

- `[^\n]*` - zero or more chars other than LF
- `Actions=QuitTeams;` - a `Actions=QuitTeams;` string
- `[^\n]*\n\?` - zero or more chars other than LF, then an optional LF char
- `\|` - operator OR
- `[^\n]*` - zero or more chars other than LF
- `\[Desktop Action QuitTeams]` - a `[Desktop Action QuitTeams]` string (note the escaped `[` in order not to define a bracket expression)
- `.*` - any text up to the file end (as `.` in a POSIX regex matches any char including line break chars).

Comment: Although it is possible to put both expressions in to one regex, the multiple `-e` option above is much clearer and easier to maintain.

Comment: @AndyLester I agree, just the OP asked to "*combine all the regexes into one*", and this is what it might look like unfortunately.

Comment: I suspect that "combine all the regexes into one" was because OP didn't know they could use multiple `-e`.